# Run step only from certain version onward in Octopus deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

I would like to know if there is a way to run certain step in Octopus from one version onward.

I see this may be achieved by defining different channels and some "Version Rules", but I think there must be a way to do this by a "Run Condition" on the step.

I saw [here](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/versioning) that you can compare versions on Octopus.

I would like to define something like this in my "Run Condition":

```
#{if Octopus.Release.Number > 2.3.15}True{/if}
```

But I don't know exactly how to write this condition. Please let me know if you can help me.

This is necessary because sometimes we add new packages (+ step) to an existing deployment, but deployments for old releases are still being creating.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Octostache](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octostache) expressions don't allow logic like this, but you can put that calculation into a script step which [outputs](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/variables/output-variables) a boolean variable that Octostache can evaluat.e

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it guided me to the solution. I have created a new answer with details.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [benPearce answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50753654/3866548) I solved my situation like this:

In a powershell step called "Check Version" I wrote:

```
$IsOver2315 = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Release.Number"] -gt [version]"2.3.15"
Set-OctopusVariable -name "IsOver2315" -value (&{If($IsOver2315) {"True"} Else {"False"}})
```

And in the "Run Condition" I wrote:

```
#{Octopus.Action[Check version].Output.IsOver2315}
```

Thanks [benPearce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4490/benpearce)